# Sequential or Parallel: statements inside a begin end block under fork join_any?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench

### How does the task1/function1 execute compared to that of task2/function2. Will it be sequential or parallel?

```
fork
forever 
 begin
     task1/function1;
     task2/function2;
 end
join_any
```

Comment: you fork a single statement only (forever loop), so, they will be executed sequentially inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your `fork/join_any` block has one statement - a `forever` loop. Your `forever` loop has one statement - a `begin/end` block. Your `begin/end` block has two(??) statements that execute sequentially. There should no question that the statements inside a `begin/end` block execute sequentially.